# "Gmaps is not defined" using Google Maps for Rails (gmaps4rails) with Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-3.1, gmaps4rails

I have a show page that should show a business and a google map of the business. I use google maps API v3. I have required `//= require gmaps4rails/googlemaps.js` in `application31.js` and added the following line into the model (business.rb):

```
  acts_as_gmappable

  def gmaps4rails_address
    "#{self.address}, #{self.city.name}, #{self.state.name}" 
  end
```

Stylesheets are also required (included). I also included gem 'gmaps4rails' into Gemfile and bundled. My model has latitude and longitude with correct values in the database.

In my business_controller.rb I have added

```
def show
  ...
  @json = Business.find(params[:id]).to_gmaps4rails
  ...
end
```

And on business show page I have added

```
%div
  = gmaps4rails(@json)
```

Footer contains

```
%footer
  = yield :scripts
```

Now the frame of google maps appears but it's empty. Here are the relevant lines concerning the error:

```
<footer>
225 <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry"></script>
226 <script type="text/javascript" src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/src/infobox_packed.js"></script>
227 <script type="text/javascript" src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.5/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"></script>
228 <script type="text/javascript" src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/src/richmarker-compiled.js"></script>
229
230 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
231
232 Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
233 Gmaps.load_map = function() {
234 Gmaps.map.map_options.auto_adjust = true;
235 Gmaps.map.initialize();
236 Gmaps.map.markers = [{"lng": "77.225", "lat": "28.6353"}];
237 Gmaps.map.markers_conf.do_clustering = true;
238 Gmaps.map.create_markers();
239 Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
240 Gmaps.map.callback();
241 };
242 window.onload = function() { Gmaps.loadMaps(); };
```

The errors now is:

```
 Gmaps is not defined" for line 232
```

Does anyone know what it can be? I also have installed geocoder, but I hope this can not create any issue.

Thanks!

Comment: there is no conflict between geocoder and gmaps4rails. The issue here is weird.

Comment: what is `application31.js` supposed to be? is it loaded by the standard `application.js`?

Comment: you are probably just missing some javascript include somewhere. are you including your application-js in the template somehwere?

Comment: Thanks, that was easy and my fault. I took over the code and thought application31.js is the new Rails 3.1 name for application.js. But it didn't load until I renamed the file to application.js. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, rename `application31.js` to `application.js`